# is it possible to center an already prefixed webpage?

Tags: html, centering

Is there anyway to overall centre a webpage that already has fixed values? I personally wouldn't have thought so, but I've spent a lot of time making a layout I'm happy with and now to centre it, it's all going to have to be rewritten. Is there any way at all to in case and centre pre-written code? Like a table? Sorry, if this is an uneducated question pretty new to code.

Any guidance or direction would be great

This what I'm after, which is currently all fixed to the left:

[image]

Comment: Probably. Can you add your code?

Comment: i can do but its really messy.. just the css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting it inside a wrapper with a fixed width and left and right margins set to auto:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 700px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- your content goes here -->
</div>
```

Comment: @aaron_m12345 - Can you give a link to your page or show the markup?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Position UI library has methods to center any element (http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/). You can call them after the document loads. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $( "#myTable" ).position({
          of: $( window ),
          my: "center",
          at: "center"});
});
```